# unable to run node.js and npm example chat

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, node.js, npm

I am trying to run different chat examples like
http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2535
I have installed npm and also node properly and its working fine. But when ever I trying to run the example code I am getting this error, which I am not able to resolve it.

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:317:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:262:25)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jeevandongre/Desktop/LearnBoost-socket.io-fbb268f/examples/chat/app.js:12:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:421:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

Comment: Do you also actually have Express.js?

Comment: @pimvdb: nope I dont have installed.How do I install that?

Comment: I have to admit I don't have it installed either, but its website is http://expressjs.com/. Some googling says you can install it by doing `npm install express`, but again I'm not sure whether it works as I haven't tried it out myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the directory with the example code, run `npm install express`, that should install it.

Important: This installation is local which means that you'll have to install it in each project you want to use it in seperately.

Comment: yup thats true even after installing I got many errors like stylus nib etc, i followed the same process and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be fixed by making sure that environment parameter `NODE_PATH` is set properly.

```
export NODE_PATH="C:\Users\IMarek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules"
```